# No wireless internet connection Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, dell, internet-connection

I just installed Ubuntu on my Dell Latitude D820.  My "wired" network is working but I have no option for "wireless" connections.  My computer has a "Nextreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express" by Broadcom.  I am completely new to Ubuntu and installed it over Windows XP.  I hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What version of Ubuntu have you installed?</strike> I answered another question similar to this one. I even had this problem myself on my Dell Inspiron. You should try to create a 'wired' connection and then create your wireless connection.

**Ubuntu 12.04** appeared to have a bug, strangely when you are asked for the 'password' Ubuntu automatically throws a failure instead of prompting for the password. This seems to occur on 12.04 only, prior versions were fine for me.